# School assignment in matlab looking for the probability of a function

Tags: matlab

heres what I have so far Im kind of confused as to if I'm going in the right direction or not 
and what to do with the function and how to calculate probability using what variables? I am new to programming so any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance

Create a code that whatever function is entered in the code (the example below will correspond to f(x) = 0.01*x.^2 + sin(0.5*2*pi*x) ), you will calculate its probability. For all functions entered x will go from 0 to 50 in increments of 0.1. To do this, you must ask the user how many bins he/she wants to use (Hint: whatever number the user chooses, add 1), and then create the bin limits. The bin limits are created by making a linear spaced array that goes from the minimum value of f(x) to the maximum value of f(x), which has the number of elements entered by the user (remember the +1 already was applied).
Now that you have the bin values, create a for loop that checks how many values of f(x) fall in each bin. Remember that the probability of each bin is calculated by # of matches/total number of points.
Once the probability of each bin is calculated, create a 2x1 subplot where the top figure is the original function vs. x. And the bottom plot is the probability of each bin vs. the bin number.

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

x = 0:50:.1; % vector for x
f = x^2;    %declaring f as a function
prompt = 'enter number of bins:'
bin = input(prompt);
binlimit = linspace(x, length(x), bin+1); 
ii = 0;
for i=1:length(binlimit)
   values = binlimit(0, end); %supposed to return values in binlimit
   prob = bin/values; %calculate probability
   disp(prob)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the function with `f = x^2`

```
x = 0:50:.1; % this is wrong
x = 0:.1:50; % from zero to 50, increment by .1
```

To obtain f(x),

```
f = 0.01*x.^2 + sin(0.5*2*pi*x)
```

I think, you can do the rest.

Comment: Okay appreciate the help why am I getting an error of "subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals?" and what do I do with the function after declaring it? How do i Integrate it into the bins?

Comment: Check which line you are getting that error. You can easily find the answer for your question. Just search in google, if you can't find ask here. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102145-why-do-i-get-the-error-subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals. Just make sure matrix index start from 1, not 0. and index is always positive integer